# como descargo automáticamente la imagen js y html2canvas

Tags: javascript

Un saludo a toda la comunidad de stack overflow, tengo una duda a ver si es posible, sobre como descargar automáticamente la imagen (obtenida de la librería html2canvas con javascript) y guardarla en una carpeta predeterminada, seria de mucha ayuda.

```js
$(function() {
            function downloadCanvas(canvasId, filename) {
            // Obteniendo la etiqueta la cual se desea convertir en imagen
            var domElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);


            html2canvas(domElement).then(domElementCanvas => {
                var context = domElementCanvas.getContext('2d');

            // Creando enlace para descargar la imagen generada
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = domElementCanvas.toDataURL("img/png");
            link.download = filename;

            // Chequeando para browsers más viejos
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            // Simulando clic para descargar
            event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                false, false, false, false,
                0, null);
            link.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
            // Simulando clic para descargar
            link.click();
        }

            // Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
        });
        }
        $('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
            var fecha = new Date();
            var year = fecha.getFullYear();
            var mon = fecha.getMonth();
            var day = fecha.getDate();
            var hour = fecha.getHours();
            var minutes = fecha.getMinutes();
            downloadCanvas('imagen', 'imagen_'+year+'_'+(mon+1)+'_'+day+'_'+hour+minutes+'.png');
        });
    });
```

Comment: La carpeta donde se guardará la imagen dependerá del usuario, no puedes siquiera proponer una ruta por defecto por temas de seguridad.

Comment: y con php es posible?

Comment: php es un lenguaje que se ejecuta en el lado del servidor

Comment: se puede enviar la imagen con ajax? y así hacer lo que se requiere?

Comment: No se puede forzar al navegador adescargar automáticamente una imagen en el PC del usuario y en la carpeta que tú elijas, da igual la tecnología que uses.

Comment: le explico mi aplicación web de monitoreo de una plataforma requiere que a la final de la tarde envié un correo o un whatsapp donde voy a obtener un capture con html2canvas el comportamiento de la plataforma y esa imagen se va almacenar en el servidor pero no se como descargarla automáticamente y guardarla en una carpeta especifica.